# How to read Settings.Secure from the NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to get access to the ANDROID_ID in Settings.Secure and it has to be from the NDK. I know there is a database which apps *might* have access to, but that's really messy. Is there anything comparable to the Secure.getString(resolver, name) method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything comparable to the Secure.getString(resolver, name) method?

Not that I am aware of. Simply have the Java code pass in the value when it calls into your JNI code. Also, bear in mind that [`ANDROID_ID` may not be useful](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).